# Less CSS import structure

Tags: css, less

I have a really big .less file that I am trying to break into smaller files for readability purposes.

But the files I am importing rely on variables and mixins from the main.less file...so they don't compile on their own.

Should I just include the variables and mixins at the top of both files, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variables and mixins are independent of the other styles (as they probably should be) you could create separate files for both variables and mixins...

```
- less_directory
  |-- mixins.less
  |-- variables.less
  |-- style1.less
  `-- style2.less
```

..and then just `import` them as needed.

Comment: this is not the best approach (because you're repeating yourself), and this is NOT the approach that bootstrap takes. better to use one main.less file as the only one that gets compiled into css, and import everything there (as posted in the other answer)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to include the variables in every file if you include them in your `main.less` file.

```
/* main.less */
@import mixins.less
@import one.less
@import two.less
```

Assuming that you're only loading `main.less` in your site, when you work on `one` or `two`, the variables from `mixins` should work just fine since everything will be compiled into `main.less`.